# Unable to delete USB Drive partitions (Block size error)

Tags: partitioning, usb

I have been unable to format/delete the partitions on my Sandisk Cruzer Force 32 GB USB Drive. I get the following error when deleting any of the partitions on it.

```
`Error deleting partition /dev/sdd2: Command-line `parted --script "/dev/sdd" "rm 2"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.
(udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Is there any way I can completely format all of my drive and turn it into one large partition? I haven't found a solution to this particular error here yet, so I thought I'd actually ASK for once

Comment: I have been using Disks. GParted does not seem to detect/display my USB Drive.

Comment: Have you tried wiping it clean first with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=2048`?  MAKE SURE YOU USE /dev/sdd ONLY IF THAT'S WHAT IT IS!

Comment: Brilliant, that worked perfectly. I'll remember those commands :)

Comment: @Daniel By the way, 5 years later and I now use dd all the time, thank you for your answer and introduction to a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

The problem you are describing was caused by a low-level device tool (like dd) writing blocks at the wrong size directly onto the device.

To fix this, you need to re-write the device blocks to the appropriate size.  This can be done with dd.
**Double check your output device before running the command**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=2048 count=32
```

Once the dd command is done, you should be able to access your device through gparted.

Comment: It sounded so right, but still didn't work for me :( Is there any way to just fix it?

Comment: Check the error reported by gparted.  The example above assumes the device size was 2048 as per OP.  Your device might have a different byte size.

Comment: I was able  to fix this error without re-writing the whole device, I just added `count=32` at the end of the command and then ran `dd`. Much faster this way ;-)

Comment: Thanks @ThatBrazilianGuy, I updated the answer to reflect your input.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy what's the meaning of `count=32`?

Comment: @Lee It will only write 32 blocks (in this case, 32 blocks of 2048 bytes, or 68 KB), instead of writing each and every byte on the device. I believe just overwriting the partition table, or equivalent area at the beginning of the device would suffice. I specified 32 blocks just to be sure.

Comment: So to be clear, `bs` should be the reported physical block size, not what "Linux says"?

Comment: My device was 8GB then I changed to count=8 and it works fine now. Thanks @gooseberry

Comment: Worked but i had to reboot my computer to make it work after using the command line.

Comment: @gooseberry I don’t think “writing blocks at the wrong size” is possible. The only difference should be speed (and in case of flash memory, wear). The command probably works, but the explanation doesn’t seem right.

Comment: This takes too long. Why must deleting a partition require overwriting the whole drive with zeros?

Comment: This overwrites the partition table, it does work, after finishing running this command you should take the USB out and plug it again. *WARNING* make sure the of= is correct or you can completely ruin your system otherwise, triple check!

Answer (score 33):

You Can always try using `fdisk`

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>ALt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdy
```

where `/dev/sdy` = The device file for your flash drive. Once you get `fdisk` open, type `p` to list the partition table, Once you know where it is located you can use `d #` to delete it. `(#` = The partition; ExAMPLE `d 1`, `d 2`) `w` writes the partition table back to the disk and `q` quits, `m` for help)

If `fdisk` fails, Then I would use `dd` **(Be careful using this it got it didn't get its nickname for no reason)**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdy bs=512 count=1
```

Of course `/dev/sdy` should be replaced with the actual device for your flash drive, will do that for you. You can increase the count= number to write zeros to more of the disk, or omit it entirely to overwrite the entire disk. Needless to say, if you do this, you irretrievably lose any files that may have been stored on the disk.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Did `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`, then at the prompt typed `d` a couple of times to delete each partition in turn, then `w` to write my changes. Then took out the USB drive, put it back in again and used the disk manager to create a Fat32 partition.

Comment: What is `dd`'s nickname?

Comment: Does it stand for `dick death` the demon slayer?

Comment: Nice! didn't need the demon slayer :|

Comment: Clearly it is nicknamed after Dexter's Lab's Dexter's sister Dee Dee, who randomly pushes any button creating all sorts of chaos

Answer (score 26):

```
wipefs -a /dev/your-device
```

it will erase all partition in your disk

Comment: This command helped me in my case when I could not format my USB drive. Be careful when choosing your device path. Double check!

Comment: updated for simplest answer that works

Answer (score 6):

This issue has something to do with UEFI based bootable disks. I frequently create bootable USB disk, then I need it for storage but can't delete the partition.

This one command below zaps the partition table so I can do whatever next I want with the USB disk.

`sudo sgdisk --zap-all /dev/???`

Replace ??? with the appropriate identifier (e.g., sdc) corresponding to the USB disk to be cleared. It can be found out by -

`sudo parted -l`

or

`sudo fdisk -l`

or

using the **disk** utility.

Comment: This is the best answer. Also see [1065719/256054](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065719/256054).

Answer (score 4):

### dd is powerful but dangerous

`dd` is a very powerful but also very dangerous tool. It works well to wipe the first part of a USB drive in order to remove any data, that might confuse the tool that you want to use. But `dd` does what you tell it to do without questions, so if you tell it to wipe your family pictures ... and a minor typing error is enough to overwrite another drive instead of the USB drive, that you intended to overwrite.

Yes, you can use `dd`, if you know what you are doing, but please check and double-check, that the command line with `dd` is correct.

### mkusb wraps a safety belt around dd

**mkusb** provides a graphical user interface with checkpoints to help you identify the target drive and double-check that you are wiping the correct drive.

There are menu options to wipe the first megabyte (actually mibibyte), which is usually enough, or the whole drive, which is a slow process, and useful only in special cases, for example when a pendrive is getting slow (for example less than half of the original speed.)

[image]

See these links for details how to install and use mkusb version 12 alias mkusb-dus.

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkUSB-quick-start-manual.pdf](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/mkUSB-quick-start-manual.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Use `fdisk` command to delete the partition and create again.

Run command:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdxY
```

(In my case, partition is 'sdb1' - replace with the correct name)

Command (`m` for help): `d` to delete the partition, choose 1 or 2.

Type `w` to save and exit.

Now eject the usb and connect again to check changes.